# A and B play a series of games which can not be drawn and p,q are their respective chances of winning a single game.

Tags: probability

Problem :

A and B play a series of games which can not be drawn and p,q are their respective chances of winning a single game. What is the chance that A wins $m$ games before B wins $n$ games.

Concept may be used :

Probability of $r$ successes  in $ n $ trials is $^nC_r $ Probability $r$ successes and $(n-r)$ failures is $p^rq^{n-r}$

How to use binomial trials here... I am not clear about this concept .. please guide  will be greatful thanks a lot........

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $A$ wins $m$ games before $B$ wins $n$ games iff from the first $n+m-1$ games at least $m$ end up in a victory for $A$.

Let's say that they play exactly $n+m-1$ games. Having done that it is for sure that $A$ won $m$ (or more) games or that $B$ won $n$ (or more) games. Let $X$ denote the number of times that $A$ wins. Then $X$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n+m-1$ and $p$. The event that $A$ wins $m$ games before $B$ wins $n$ games is exactly the event that $X\geq m$. So you have to calculate $P\left\{ X\geq m\right\}$. See the answer of Cameron for a formula for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, here, that the games are independent. Let's say that A and B will keep playing games until A has won $m$ games, but that B will be declared the winner if B wins $n$ games before that happens, while player A will be declared the winner otherwise.

First, let's find the probability that the process will terminate after game number $x$, where $x$ is some positive integer, and let $X$ be the number of games played in total. Clearly, $P(X=x)=0$ when $x<m$. (Why?) Now, if $X=x,$ then as of game number $x-1$, player A had won $m-1$ of the $x-1$ games, and player B had won the other $x-m$ games. After that, player A won game number $x.$ How likely was this to have happened? Well, there are $\binom{x-1}{m-1}$--alternate notation for ${}^{x-1}C_{m-1}$--different ways in which the wins and losses in the first $x-1$ games could be distributed, and since the games are independent, then the probability that player A won $m-1$ of the first $x-1$ games is $$\binom{x-1}{m-1}p^{m-1}q^{x-m}.$$ Since the probability that player A wins game number $x$ is again $p$, then independence shows us that $$P(X=x)=\begin{cases}\binom{x-1}{m-1}p^mq^{x-m} & \text{for }x=m,m+1,m+2,m+3,...\\0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

In order to find the desired probability, then, we need simply add up $P(X=x)$ for those $x$ for which player A was the ultimate winner. In particular, player A won if and only if no more than $n+m-1$ games were played. (Why?) Hence, the probability you're looking for is $$\sum_{x=m}^{n+m-1}P(X=x)=\sum_{x=m}^{n+m-1}\binom{x-1}{m-1}p^mq^{x-m}.$$